# Changing the default HTML editor in IE10?

Tags: internet-explorer

Is there a way to change the default editor in IE10 from Notepad to Notepad++?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a quite old request, but:

For IE9 and later:

- Open Internet Explorer
- hit **F12** to open the developer tools
- click **File**
- click **Customize Internet Explorer view source**

If **"Other"** is checked, try

1. first to change to option **"Notepad"**
2. second re-change it to **"Other"**: You'll be asked for the application then (select you texteditor).

kr, zara

Comment: I'm not seeing "Customize Internet Explorer view source" under the file menu of IE11 and I am not seeing a file menu under developer tools.

Answer (score 2):

Open a command prompt as administrator and run this command (change the path to Notepad++ if necessary):

```
REG ADD "HKCR\.htm\OpenWithList\Notepad++\shell\edit\command" /ve /d "\"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe\" %1"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View Source Editor]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\View Source Editor\Editor Name]
@="C:\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"
```

Here notepad is installed in the path `C:\Notepad++\notepad++.exe`.

Comment: It's better to place in code format

Comment: In enterprise windows 10 (connected to domain), location is in user register, so use search to find "View Source Editor". If it does not exists, first use internet explorer settings and in Programs tab select source editor notepad.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer also worked in Internet Explorer 11, running in Windows 8.1 (with April 14th KB updates), FYI.

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, but it was quite helpful for those of us concerned if it will work with IE 11

Comment: Thanks for saying that SvdSinner, btw.  I learned my lesson. :)